# setting location for checkox in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am writing an online reservation system application. User can select an activity with checkbox. Then, they can submit to their reservations. I am having a problem with checkbox location and I don't know how to submit these checked reservations with submit button.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Book Ticket</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>    
<table border="1" width="30%" height="30%">
    <tr><th><font color='#D18603'>Activity ID.</font></th>
        <th><font color='#D18603'>Type</font></th>
        <th><font color='#D18603'>Description</font></th>
        <th><font color='#D18603'>City</font></th>
        <th><font color='#D18603'>Location</font></th>
        <th><font color='#D18603'>Date</font></th>
        <th><font color='#D18603'>Price</font></th>
        <th><font color='#D18603'>Buy</font></th>
    </tr>
    <td><b><font color='#663300'><input type="checkbox" name="ticket"       value=""/></font></td></b>



    <%
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from activities");
        while (rs.next()) {

            String activityid1 = rs.getString("id");
            String type1 = rs.getString("type");
            String description1 = rs.getString("description");
            String city1 = rs.getString("city");
            String location1 = rs.getString("location");
            String date1 = rs.getString("date");
            String price1 = rs.getString("price");

            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>" + activityid1 + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + type1 + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + description1 + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + city1 + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + location1 + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + date1 + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + price1 + "</td>");

            out.println("</tr>");

        }


    %>

 </center>
 </table></body>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="10"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
 <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
 </tr> 
 <br><br><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>  
 </html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by checkbox location ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, put *checkbox* in while loop and *checkbox's value* have activityid1. Surround the code with a form. Create java servlet or another jsp.

```
<form method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/TestServlet">
 <table 
 <tr>
   ...
while (rs.next()) {

   int activityid1 = rs.getInt("id");
   String type1 = rs.getString("type");
                ...

   out.println("<tr>");
   out.println("<td>" + activityid1 + "</td>");
   out.println("<td>" + type1 + "</td>");
   out.println("<td><b><font color='#663300'><input type='checkbox' name='ticket' value='"+activityid1+"'/></font></td></b>");

   out.println("</tr>");

 }
 </table>
    <td colspan="10"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
 </form>
```

[image]

Submit form and you can get checked values in another jsp such as *test.jsp* or TestServlet.

```
String [] val = request.getParameterValues("ticket");
```

Finally, save activityids with user_id

You can look this. [MVC in JSP](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp)

Also you can use JSTL library. Not recommended writing more java code in JSP page. Connect database in Java class.

I hope it will be help.

Comment: i cannot understand submit part